# How can I use javascript to allow for audio interactions?

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to build a web application that plays certain music notes when users click on certain buttons. I examined other applications that involve much audio interaction, and a lot of them (such as [Google's doodle for Moog's 78th birthday](http://www.google.com/doodles/robert-moogs-78th-birthday)) use such technologies as Flash.

I don't want to use Flash since Flash may not be available on all mobile devices. How can I allow for audio interaction with javascript and without Flash?

Comment: Check this out: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API

Comment: From the above URL.

"Please note that this document describes a non-standard experimental API."

Comment: Thanks! That page was pretty inspirational. What if I just used the w3c Web Audio API (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) for now? It is currently supported by Chrome and nightly builds of Safari according to http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/index.html.

Comment: The Audio Data API has been rejected by W3C, so it won't be supported in the future (as far as I understand). The Web Audio API however is still in the running and the other browser vendors (Mozilla, Opera) are currently getting involved in the development, so I'd say that's your best bet. The Web Audio API will also be included in the new Safari in iOS6.

Comment: And, of course, I assume you have already considered the <audio>-element?

Comment: Actually, using the audio element sounds like a good idea! Thanks. I just hope that javascript is able to alter the volume and restart the sound of the audio tag when appropriate.